# Why does the reduced Chi-squared around 1 not zero?

Tags: statistics, optimization, data-analysis, chi-squared

It is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic) that the reduced Chi-squared $\chi^2/dof$ is always compared to 1 and it determines the goodness of fitting, where $\chi^2$ is defined as: $$\chi^2=\sum{\frac{(model-data)^2}{\sigma^2}}$$ Meanwhile as I know the $\chi^2$ represents the sum of the squared residuals, so if the model represents the best fit, does not this lead to the sum of the residuals tends to zero and the best fitting should be zero?
I know that $\sigma$ can be used for scaling, but does it mean that even if we have one set of data and we perform fitting with several models should we use different $\sigma$ for each model.
I think that I might have a misconception.

Comment: That division by $\sigma_i^2$ suggests there should be some random fluctuation even under the null hypothesis: indeed $\sigma_i^2 = E[(model_i-data_i)^2]$ under the null hypothesis. Since a $\chi^2$-distributed  random variable is non-negative this results in a positive expectation equal to the number of degrees of freedom. Scale for that and you get $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confuse “true model” and “no standard deviation.” We have an assumption that the observations come from a Gaussian generative process $y_i\sim N(X_i^T\beta, \sigma_i^2)$ for each $i$. If this true model is found, the $\chi^2$ statistic $\sum_i \left(\frac{(y_i-f(x_n|\beta))^2}{\sigma_i^2}\right)$ will be $\chi$-square with n df because it is the sum of n Gaussian random variates squared. The expectation is n, so divided by the degrees of freedom, n, we get 1 for the correct model.

If the statistic is greater than 1, generally it implies underfitting (residuals too large), while less than 1 means overfitting. This is done logically by comparison with the fact that it is 1 under the true model, but in practice it can be [complicated](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3754.pdf).

On the other hand, if the standard deviations were all $0$, we’d get a perfect fit with no residuals, but we cannot have a zero standard deviation in the Gaussian model. The model would be deterministic with no randomness. A chi-square statistic would be inappropriate.

Comment: @jellfish, Is there any other statistical parameter that can be use to compare between different fitting models to determine the best fit one?
cause i have the following problem, As i understand that $\sigma$ scales the residuals, and if it is correctly determined then $\chi^2/dof$ will be around 1. in my case the uncertainites of the data i have gives $\chi^2/dof$ around 0.033, and i cant find the right scale.

Comment: @Gibrate It depends on how you are fitting the model. If you are fitting it the frequentist way, you can use AIC or BIC of the model; the one with the lesser is usually better.